# jQuery - Partial Query Searches Through a Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: jquery, search, multidimensional-array, partial

Please can someone help me? I'm new to jQuery.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
//classcCars = [Year,  Car Name,  Owner's Name]
var classcCars = [
    [1927, "Ford Model T", "Brian"],
    [1969, "Corvette Sting Ray", "Larry"],
    [1967, "Ford Mustang", "John"],
    [1969, "Camaro SS", "Samantha"],
    [1967, "Volkswagen Beetle"],
    [1964, "Porsche 911", "Michael"],
    [1962, "Maserati 3500", "Loren"],
    [1967, "Ford GT40", "Sarah"]
];
```

I'd like a jQuery function that can iterate through the "classicCars" array (searching only in section ***[1]*** and ***[2]***, the *Car Name* and the *Owners Name*)and return the corresponding year and name of a car and the car's owner, using a partial string. So for example, calling:

```
findCars("Porsche");
```

Should return:

```
<p>Michael Porsche 911 - 1964</p>
```

Also, the findCars() function should return more than 1 entry. If the following function were called:

```
findCars("or");
```

The following should get return:

```
<p>Brian owns a Ford Model T - 1927</p>
<p>Larry owns a Corvette Sting Ray - 1969</p>
<p>John owns a Ford Mustang - 1967</p>
<p>Michael owns a Porsche 911 - 1964</p>
<p>Loren owns a Maserati 3500 - 1964</p>
<p>Sarah owns a Ford GT40 - 1967</p>
```

Can someone kindly help me? I have no idea how to do partial searches in a multi-dimensional array in jQuery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function searchArr( keyword ) {

  var retVal = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < classcCars.length; i++ ) {
    for( var j = 0; j < classcCars[ i ].length; j++ ) {
      if( String( classcCars[ i ][ j ] ).toLowerCase().indexOf( String( keyword ).toLowerCase(), 0 ) != -1 ) {
        retVal.push( classcCars[ i ] );
      }
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

(sorry for the previous typos)

This is just to point you in the right direction - the function will return an array containing only the elements from your classcCars array that contain the keyword.

Se example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QtkAf/3/

Comment: Thanks MTDK,My question is would that do a **partial** search, so _"or"_ will bring up _"ford"_ and _"Loren"_?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code isn't working. See here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QtkAf/)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var findCars = (function () {
    function found( str, substr ) {
       return str && substr && str.indexOf( substr ) > -1;
    }

    return function ( arr, term ) {
        return arr.filter( function ( elem ) {
            return found( elem[1], term ) || found( elem[2], term );
        }).map( function ( elem ) {
            return template({ name: elem[2], car: elem[1], year: elem[0] });
        }).join( '' );
    };
}());
```

I'm using a Handlebars template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>{{name}} {{car}} - {{year}}</p>
</script>
```

Usage:

```
var html_string = findCars( classcCars, 'Porsche' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yLcmZ/